# Bokeh Select widget does not update plot glyph

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I am programming a Bokeh application and trying to implement a select widget. Before I had my whole plot with glyph etc. in one function and used this function as the callback function for my select widget and everything worked fine. But the performance was pretty bad. So, I tried to make the plot outside of a function and then the callback functions separately. Now the select widget does not work properly anymore. I do not get any error when starting the application (I use the Bokeh serve --show main.py method). The select widget shall change the values of the y-axis and update the y-axis label at the same time. The label gets updated but the values are not changing. My code looks like this:

```
sel_yaxis = Select(
    title='Select Y Axis',
    options=sorted(head_columns.keys()),
    value='Demonstrative word'
)

def set_axis(attr, old, new):
    # Save value for y-axis from select input widget within the "top" variable
    # in the glyph. It will automatically update on changing the select widget within the application.
    y_axis = head_columns[sel_yaxis.value]

    # Set the label on y-axis so that the glyph displayed and y-axis label match
    p.yaxis.axis_label = sel_yaxis.value
    c.yaxis.axis_label = sel_yaxis.value

sel_yaxis.on_change('value', set_axis)

p = figure(
    title='',
    plot_width=1000,
    plot_height=700,
    x_axis_label='ID',
    toolbar_location='above',
    tools='pan, box_select, save, undo, redo, xwheel_zoom, reset'
)

c = figure(
    title='',
    plot_width=1000,
    plot_height=700,
    x_axis_label='ID',
    toolbar_location='above',
    tools='pan, box_select, save, undo, redo, xwheel_zoom, reset'
)

# Holds the x-axis ID values for the glyph
id = head_columns['id']

p.yaxis.axis_label = sel_yaxis.value
c.yaxis.axis_label = sel_yaxis.value

# Render glyph into plot
p.vbar(
    x=id,
    top=y_axis,
    source=source,
    width=0.8,
    line_alpha=0.3,
)

c.scatter(
    x=id,
    y=y_axis,
    source=source
)
```

The same way it was working good within one main function to create the plot.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: It will be much easier for others to help you if you can post a ***complete, minimal example*** that is jsut enough to demonstrate the single issue you are asking about.

Comment: Do you think it is better this way? This is all code i use to change the glyph.

Comment: I should be more explicit. By *complete, minimal reproducer* I mean something I can literally copy and paste into an editor and run, myself, with no modifications whatsoever necessary on my part. The code above is not complete (e.g. it has not imports at all)

Comment: It's also not clear what "change the values of the y-axis" means. Do you mean change the data that is plotted? Your callback makes no attempt to do that. It changes the axis title property, which does nothing beyond changing the axis title. It does not affect any other data anywhere. There are lots of examples of updating data based on widgets: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app

Comment: The problem is, that I am using a specific .tsv file which I cant provide. That one is read in with pandas and a columndatasource is created used as the source for the glyph. Without this file you will get an error I think.

Comment: I try to explain it to you. For 'y', respectively 'top', the variable y_axis is given. At the first time running the app it is instantiated with 'y_axis = head_columns[sel_yaxis.value]'. The head_columns provides a value which is a column of my ColumnDataSource. When I change the value of my select widget it should upgrade the y-axis variable, so that the plot will render data from another column of my ColumnDataSource. It worked in exactly this way a few hours ago, but now its broken and I can not explain why.

Comment: You need to actually *modify the CDS that the plot is using* , if you want the plot to update. Your callback does not do that. Lots of the examples I linked do do exactly the kind of update you are asking about. Look for lines like `source.data = new_data`.